# change Date and time in ago format in google api javascript

Tags: javascript, rss

I am making a div in javascript and display data in this div. I want that the
 date and time should be shown in '1min ago' format.

```
 var div2 = document.createElement("div");
 div2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.publishedDate));
 div2.setAttribute("id", "date");
```

Answer (score 0):

The key to showing date in particular format is in **entry.publishDate**. You should post the date that you are getting in the API for further help.

There is no prewritten function in javascript that will change in particular date format. You need a custom function for that(which you can find easily on the web).